# How to properly offset the beginning of a fluid simulation?

Tags: fluid-simulation

To offset the beginning of a fluid simulation you only have to set the Start of the fluid's domain to anything above 0 seconds. However, by doing so, the results differ from starting at time 0.

For example we can compare this two simulations with one inflow at 200 resolution in a scene with 1 second of duration (from 0 to 23 at 24 fps):

1. The first simulation's Start and End are set from 0 to 1

[image]

2. The second simulation's Start and End are set from 1 to 2

[image]

In this case the **last** frame of the first simulation may be the same as the **first** frame of the second simulation.

As you can see below, the result differ.

[image]
[image]

As [this post says](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5072/for-fluid-simulation-what-do-the-start-end-and-speed-settings-mean), this is the proper workflow when offsetting the beginning of a fluid simulation. However, in the offsetted simulation it appears that the inflow velocity is higher and thus there is more fluid.

This difference **is more noticeable when you increase the resolution**. I usually make a bake with Start 0 and then decide how many seconds of offsetting I'll put. Then when I bake again -with, say, 3.6 seconds as Start time- the result is **a lot** different from expected working at 650 resolution.

Then, the final question is, **what's the proper workflow for offsetting the start of a simulation but maintain the result you might have when not doing so?**