# Fluid smulation start Time

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, fluid-simulation

l want to make a water simulation. The fluid simulation should start after 600 frame but when l setup to simulation it starts immediately at frame one and l want it to start at frame 600. how can l make this. l couldn't find the solution. l'm using blender V2.79

Comment: Related: [For Fluid Simulation, what do the Start, End and Speed settings mean?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5072/for-fluid-simulation-what-do-the-start-end-and-speed-settings-mean)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set your framerate to 30fps, (easier to calculate), and set the fluid domain to start at **20** and to end a certain amount of seconds later. Now there is a trick to this: the numbers here are the duration of the animation divided by the framerate of your animation currently. I.e. 300 frames / 30fps = 10 fluid seconds. If you want to end your fluid simulation at frame 900, then set the fluid domain to end at 30 seconds. Here is where you control these settings:[image]

Comment: Thank you so much it is worked :)